# VScode PHPCS Extension Error: Referenced Sniff "WordPress-Core" does not exist

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-studio-code, phpcs

**I want to add PHP CodeSniffer to VScode.**

Within VScode I am getting the error `'phpcs: Referenced sniff "WordPress-Core" does not exist'`

However when I run the following command in the terminal: 
`phpcs --standard="WordPress-Core" dropdowns.php`
PHP CodeSniffer works as expected with the following terminal output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 34 ERRORS AND 17 WARNINGS AFFECTING 51 LINES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  15 | WARNING | [x] Array double arrow not aligned correctly; expected 10
     |         |     space(s) between "'id'" and double arrow, but found 1.
  17 | WARNING | [x] Array double arrow not aligned correctly; expected 4
     |         |     space(s) between "'taxonomy'" and double arrow, but found
     |         |     1.
  18 | WARNING | [x] Array double arrow not aligned correctly; expected 5
     |         |     space(s) between "'orderby'" and double arrow, but found
     |         |     1.
  34 | WARNING | [x] Equals sign not aligned with surrounding assignments;
     |         |     expected 10 spaces but found 1 space
  35 | WARNING | [x] Equals sign not aligned with surrounding assignments;
     |         |     expected 7 spaces but found 1 space
  36 | ERROR   | [x] Short array syntax is not allowed
  44 | WARNING | [x] Equals sign not aligned with surrounding assignments;
     |         |     expected 2 spaces but found 1 space
  84 | WARNING | [x] Equals sign not aligned with surrounding assignments;
     |         |     expected 2 spaces but found 1 space
```

My settings.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "phpcs.standard": "WordPress",
    "phpcs.executablePath": "/Users/michelle/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs",
    "phpcs.enable": true,
    "phpcs.showWarnings": true,
    "phpcs.showSources": true,
}
```

My phpcs.ruleset.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="WordPress Theme Coding Standards">
    <description>My Project's Coding Standards</description>
    <rule ref="~/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs/WordPress-Docs"/>
    <rule ref="~/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs/WordPress-Extra"/>
    <rule ref="~/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs/WordPress"/>
    <rule ref="~/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs/WordPress-Core"/>
    <rule ref="~/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs/WordPressVIPMinimum"/>
    <rule ref="~/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs/WordPress-VIP-Go"/>
</ruleset>
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this error by updating the rule references in this file: 
`~/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs/WordPress`to also be absolute paths. Final ruleset.xml for WordPress coding standards now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="WordPress" namespace="WordPressCS\WordPress" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/master/phpcs.xsd">

    <description>WordPress Coding Standards</description>

    <rule ref="~/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs/WordPress-Core"/>
    <rule ref="~/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs/WordPress-Docs"/>
    <rule ref="~/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs/WordPress-Extra">
        <!-- Prevent duplicate messages + deprecation notice from deprecated sniff. -->
        <exclude name="WordPress.WP.TimezoneChange.timezone_change_date_default_timezone_set"/>
        <exclude name="WordPress.WP.TimezoneChange.DeprecatedSniff"/>
    </rule>

</ruleset>
```

Comment: This was useful to me: https://jasonyingling.me/setting-up-wordpress-coding-standards-in-visual-studio-code/

Comment: and of course the docs: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage#using-a-default-configuration-file

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that you're using multiple versions of `phpcs`.

Try, in a shell:

```
which phpcs
```

If you get something like `/usr/bin/phpcs`, you have the package installed with your system's package manager. Either manage it using the package manager -- install `WordPress-Core` with `apt` or `brew` or whatever you're using -- or remove it (then try again).

If you don't get a result, try to [install PHPCS globally using Composer](https://janw.me/today-i-learned/installing-wordpress-coding-standards-globally/). Make sure `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin` is in your `PATH`.

At this point, you know the path of the executable that you *want* to use, and you know *where* it is. Now:

```
phpcs -i
```

That will give you a list of installed standards. Mine says: `MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz, Zend, PHPCompatibility, PHPCompatibilityParagonieRandomCompat, PHPCompatibilityParagonieSodiumCompat, PHPCompatibilityWP, WordPress-Core, WordPress-Docs, WordPress-Extra and WordPress`.

You know where your executable is and you know how to modify it (either Composer with `global`, or `apt`, or `brew`, or whatever). Keep installing until you get the right thing.

If you're using a PHPCS extension in VS Code and you haven't specified a full path to the executable, it may be checking in your project path. Given how easy it is to set up Composer with lots of stuff, it may be finding another copy of the executable.

Set the extension to point to the correct executable. Now it should be able to find all the standards you need.

Also make sure that you're not running multiple VS Code extensions. If you're anything like me, when you move to a new install, you go and install 50 extensions of all the things you think you may need one day. Some meta-extensions come with PHPCS, commonly bundled with a formatter, or, "everything you need to code in VS Code in PHP." Make sure that either:

- only one extension is linting, or,
- all linters are pointing to the correct `phpcs` executable.

This should fix this issue permanently.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make all installed coding standards available to phpcs:

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths full-wpcs-path\WordPress,full-wpcs-path\WordPress-Core,full-wpcs-path\WordPress-Docs,full-wpcs-path\WordPress-Extra
```

see phpcs.standard in:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.phpcs